# What is "more carefully than I do" in "My wife drives more carefully than I do", grammatically?

Tags: adverbs, phrases, clauses, parsing, complements

Consider this sentence:

> My wife drives more carefully than I do.

I want to understand the grammatical role of the phrase,

> more carefully than I do

Is it an adverb, and adverb phrase, an adverb clause, an adverb complement or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to English Language Learners.

In this sentence, the phrase, 'more carefully than I do', is an adverbial phrase. It can't be considered an [adverbial clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/135945/adverbial-phrase-vs-adverbial-clause) because it doesn't have its own subject and verb. It can't be considered an [adverbial complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_complement) because it's not necessary for the meaning of the verb, 'to drive'.

An example of an adverbial clause would be

> My wife drives *when she wants our trip to be safe*.

It starts with a subordinating conjunction and has a separate subject and verb.

An example of an adverbial complement where the verb is 'to drive away' would be

> My wife drives *away* when I offer to get behind the wheel.

Comment: Thank you .  I know that the structure of an adverb phrase is as follows:
adverb / adverb + adverb.
but phrase  'more carefully than I do' !!

Comment: Can I say that  'more carefully ' is adverb , ' than I do ' is prepositional phrase  that 
' I do ' is noun clause and ' I do ' complement for " more carefully.

Comment: It looks to me like those are accurate descriptions of those parts of the sentence by themselves. Taken together they form the adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 0):

"carefully" is an adverb modifying "drive". The surrounding words "more ... than I do" modifies "carefully". The entire phrase remains an adverbial phrase; the modification doesn't change the part of speech. You can apply it to a noun and get a noun phrase ("My wife takes more care than I do"), an adjective and get an adjectival phrase ("My wife is more careful than I am"), etc.